# Publish Content Type PnP Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, content-type, publishing, pnp-powershell

I need a group of content types to be created in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint online using PnP PowerShell commands.

How do I publish these content types using PnP PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

To Create a Content Type using PnP PowerShell, you need to use the command like given below:

```
Add-PnPContentType -Name "Project Document" -Description "Use for Contoso projects" -Group "Contoso Content Types" -ParentContentType $ct
```

Check below article for syntax and list of parameters and their description:

[Add-PnPContentType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpcontenttype).

For official documentation and installation of PnP PowerShell check below documentation:

[PnP PowerShell overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets).

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If Yes, please upvote(^) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the two articles below:

[Create And Delete SharePoint Content Type using Pnp powershell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pnp-powershell-cmdlets-with-sharepoint-online-part-three/)

[Use PnP PowerShell to add ContentType for your SharePoint site](https://powershell.org/2018/08/use-pnp-powershell-to-add-contenttype-for-your-sharepoint-site/)